# Element is not removing from vector after convert from json to vector

Tags: java, android, json, vector, gson

I have a data model like this:

```
    public class Person {
        String name = "";
        Integer id;
        public Person() {
            name = "";
            id = new Integer(0);
        }
    }
```

First I have created 2 objects and added in a vector. Converted the vector into json string. After doing some checking again I have converted the json string into vector. Inside the vector it's showing the correct number of elements and data. But when I am trying to get position of one object it's returning -1. Even using vector.remove() I am unable to remove the object. If I don't convert the vector into json string it's working fine. Following is my code:

```
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Vector vecResult = new Vector();

        Person person = new Person();
        person.name = "ABC";
        person.id = new Integer(1001);

        vecResult.add(person);

        Person person2 = new Person();
        person2.name = "DEF";
        person2.id = new Integer(1002);

        vecResult.add(person2);

        String json = gson.toJson(vecResult); //successful

        Type token = new TypeToken<Vector<Person>>() {}.getType();
        Vector<Person> vecResults = gson.fromJson(json3, token); //vecResults got 2 objects
        int pos = vecResults.indexOf(person); //returning -1
        boolean isRemoved = vecResults.remove(person); // returning false
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to override following

```
boolean equals(Object obj) 
int     hashCode()
```

Your code is not working because `Vector#remove` uses following for getting index.

```
public synchronized int indexOf(Object o, int index) {
    if (o == null) {
        for (int i = index ; i < elementCount ; i++)
        if (elementData[i]==null)
            return i;
    } else {
        for (int i = index ; i < elementCount ; i++)
        if (o.equals(elementData[i]))
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
    }
```

Please note default implementation for equals is as follows

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `Person` class doesn't override `equals()` (or `hashCode()`).

When you serialize to JSON and then deserialize, that will create new instances of `Person` - which are entirely non-equal to the original ones as far as `indexOf` and `remove` are concerned. They happen to have the same `name` and `id` values, but that doesn't automatically make them equal.

Override `Object.equals()` and `Object.hashCode()` for whatever meaning of equality you want (just name? just ID? both?) and it should be fine.

Note that it's generally better to make fields private, and provide property getters/setters.

Answer (score 0):

remove() tries to loacte the object via the equals() method. By default this is the object identity. Generate an explicit equals() method for person (in eclipse you can just generate one using all fields).
(When overriding equals() you also need to have a matching hashcode() method)